# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: RestaurantListServiceProvider <- RestaurantListService <- ReservationController

Tags: angularjs

Here I have my RestaurantList service as follows

```
var restaurantList = angular.module("service.restaurantList", []);
restaurantList.service('RestaurantListService', ['$rootScope',   'BackendService', 'toaster', '$cookieStore', 'getConstants', 'principal', '$state',
function ($rootScope, BackendService, toaster, $cookieStore, getConstants, principal, $state) {
/*
*/
}])
```

I have my code for the reservation.js as follows

```
var app = angular.module('reservation', ['angularMoment']);

app.controller('ReservationController',['$scope', 'ngDialog', 'BackendService','ReservationService','RestaurantListService', '$rootScope', 'toaster', "$timeout", "checkEmpty",
"$interval", "principal",
function ($scope, ngDialog, BackendService, ReservationService,RestaurantListService, $rootScope, toaster, $timeout, checkEmpty, $interval, principal) {
/*
*/
}])
```

In the Reservation Controller I am injecting ReservationList service. Now it gives the error

```
angular.js:12798 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:    RestaurantListServiceProvider <- RestaurantListService <- ReservationController
```

Comment: have you refered the service in view?

Comment: I have referred it but still the same error

Answer (score 1):

That error is coming because you are having your service defined in a separate module. Here you are defining two modules for your application ('**service.restaurantList**' & '**reservation**') . Try to add the dependency of child module in to your parent module like this.

```
var app = angular.module('reservation', ['angularMoment', 'service.restaurantList']);
```

Comment: Now it shows this error Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module service.restaurantList due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'service.restaurantList' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Did u include ur code of defining that service.restaurantList before defining ur parent module ?

Comment: I have forget to add it in the parent module. Thank u